# How do I get a list by supplying an email in the query parameter of the get_entry_list API call?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I'm trying to update a specific Lead from Sugar CRM. I do not know the ID of this lead, so I'm trying to retrieve the lead ID by calling get_entry_list using email addresses or names. I wanted to use a query and specify an email address or a name like so:

```
    'query' => "first_name = \"Bob\"",
```

I even tried:

```
    'query' => "first_name LIKE \"%Bob%\"",
```

and

```
    'query' => "email1 LIKE \"%bob@abc.com\"",
```

But I just get this result:

`Database failure. Please refer to sugarcrm.log for details.`

...and there's nothing inside *sugarcrm.log* :(

---

Here's the full code:

```
$get_entry_list_parameters = array(

//session id
'session' => $session_id,

//The name of the module from which to retrieve records
'module_name' => 'Leads',

//The SQL WHERE clause without the word "where".
'query' => "first_name = \"Bob\"",

//The SQL ORDER BY clause without the phrase "order by".
'order_by' => "",

//The record offset from which to start.
'offset' => '0',

//Optional. A list of fields to include in the results.
'select_fields' => array(
    'id',
    'name',
    'email1',
),

'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(
),

//The maximum number of results to return.
'max_results' => '10',

//To exclude deleted records
'deleted' => '0',

//If only records marked as favorites should be returned.
'Favorites' => false,
);

$get_entry_list_result = call('get_entry_list', $get_entry_list_parameters, $url);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($get_entry_list_result);
echo '</pre>';
```

---

**EDIT**: I'm using v4_1 REST API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this a running example > http://urdhva-tech.blogspot.in/2013/02/rest-api-example.html

Hope you find it useful.

Else by looking at the $get_entry_list_parameters array, it looks like it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for this davidboris. I specified the table name in my query like you did in your example and that seemed to work! `leads.email1 = \"bob@abc.com\"` works!!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in service/v4/SugarWebServiceUtilv4.php beginning in line 78. Set a breakpoint there or log the query ($where) that was generated. Maybe this helps you find out the reason.